# How to Serialize Java Objects in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, serialization

I am send a List Of Stock Objects from my servlet to JSP using server sent events as shown below

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        List<Stock> list = new ArrayList<Stock>();
         response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        response.addHeader("Refresh", "20");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                Stock st = new Stock();
                st.setPrice("123");
                st.setSymbol("BPCL");
                list.add(st);
            }

        out.write("data: "+ list + "\n\n");
    }
}
```

This is the jsp which is listening to above  servlet

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
    <script>

        function registerSSE()
        {
            var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:8086/StreamFromShareKhan/StreamServlet');  
            source.onmessage=function(event)
            {
               alert(event.data);
            };


        }
    </script>
    <output id ="result"></output>

    <input type="button" onclick="registerSSE()" value="View Good Stocks">

</body>
</html>
```

The alert is being displayed:

```
 [com.Stock@1cd7a270, com.Stock@10e975db]
```

Comment: What is `event.data`? (text please, no image, and maybe it's not a string?) And what do you want to iterate?

Comment: What is your question? What does not work as expected?

Comment: Can't read your image. Too small. Please post the text. Can you make the server send JSON?

Comment: i tried printing event.data through  console.log(event.data); which printed [com.Stock@1cd7a270, com.Stock@10e975db]  , i have no clue how to debug further .  Please tell me how can i further debug ??

Comment: i tried printing event.data through  console.log(event.data); which printed [com.Stock@1cd7a270, com.Stock@10e975db]  , i have no clue how to debug further .

Comment: @PreethiJain: I suspect your problem is on the servlet side and it's just doing a `toString` on your objects rather than properly serializing them, but I don't know servlets. This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) seems to suggest thats exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd either want to iterate over it with a [for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) like this:

```
for ( value in event.data )
{
    // do something with value here
    console.log( value );
}
```

or use [jQuery's each() method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each( event.data, function( index, value )
{
    // do something with the stuff here
    console.log( index, value );
} );
```